# Post uploaded facebook video to friend's wall via ios sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook-graph-api

I am able to post a video to a friends wall if I take a url like this:

```
http://www.facebook.com/video/video.php?v=10150344412195987
```

and put that in the "Write something ...." field on their wall.  It posts exactly how I want.  However if I try posting via the graph api using this:

```
NSString *postUrl = @"http://www.facebook.com/video/video.php?v=10150344412195987";
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    @"post this", @"message",
                                    postUrl, @"source",
NSString *graphPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"me/feed"];    
FBRequest *req = [facebook requestWithGraphPath:graphPath
                                    andParams:params
                                    andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                                    andDelegate:requestDelegate];
```

I get this error:

```
(#100) FBCDN image is not allowed in stream: http://www.facebook.com/video/video.php?v=10150344412195987
```

Is there any way around this?  I also tried using the "link" parameter instead of "source" but then I get this error:

```
Error Domain=facebookErrDomain Code=10000 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (facebookErrDomain error 10000.)" UserInfo=0x7fabf70 {error=<CFBasicHash 0x7fa4b90 [0x273a380]>{type = mutable dict, count = 2,
entries =>
2 : <CFString 0x7facfb0 [0x273a380]>{contents = "type"} = <CFString 0x7fb4370 [0x273a380]>{contents = "OAuthException"}
3 : <CFString 0x7fb4630 [0x273a380]>{contents = "message"} = <CFString 0x7fb4a50 [0x273a380]>{contents = "An unknown error has occurred."}
}
}'
```

Why am I able to post by hand to my friends wall but not through the graph api?

EDIT: if I could tag a user in a video that would be the ideal solution.

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed to directly upload images/videos that are hosted on the fbcdn.net domain. This is a limitation that was put in place because the media was not always optimized. That is what this error means.

If you want to see how to upload a video to a user's wall see the How-To blog post https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/532/ but in your case you may want to first download the video locally before uploading it via Graph API.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.facebook.com/video/video.php?v=10150344412195987"];
NSData * videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

Comment: The video originally came from the iphone. This was an attempt to share as an authorized user to a friend's wall. Something like @"<friendid>/videos" or @"<friendid>/wall". This gives the same error as above ... again even though I'm supplying a video using: NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:movFilePath];

Comment: Two questions: 1) Are you able to post the video to your wall? 2) Can you post something other than a video to your friend's wall? You should use me/feed to post.