# Post Video on Facebook friend wall in iPhone (Graph API)

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, share

I integrated Graph API in my iOS Application.Its working fine. 
I Need to implement share video on fb. How can we share video in Graph API? 
Please give same idea about this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Its's not share,it is called post.
Visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7141189/post-uploaded-facebook-video-to-friends-wall-via-ios-sdk

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19588522/how-to-share-video-in-facebook-sdk?rq=1